# TypeError: DoubleLinkedList.add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error. I go through this concept but could not find the error. I am making a link list but when giving values it's showing me this error **TypeError: DoubleLinkedList.add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**I got through the below concept but I could not find the error or what to do. I am new in python programming

````
        class Node:
            def __init__(self, value):
                self.next = None
                self.prev = None
                self.val = value
        
        
        class DoubleLinkedList:
            def __init__(self, ):
                self.head = None
                self.tail = None
                self.size = 0
        
            def add(self):
                node = Node()
                if self.tail is None:
                    self.head = node
                    self.tail = node
                    self.size += 1
                else:
                    self.tail.next = node
                    node.prev = self.head
                    self.tail = node
                    self.size += 1
        
            def __str__(self):
                vals = []
                node = self.head
                while node is not Node:
                    vals.append(node.val)
                    node = node.next
                return f"[{','.join((str(val) for val in vals))}]"
        
        
        my_list = DoubleLinkedList()
        
        my_list.add(1)
        my_list.add(5)
        my_list.add(2)
        
        print(my_list)
    
    ```
````

Comment: Your `add` function is missing something like a `value` parameter that you should then pass to `Node(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your add function like this

```
    def add(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self.tail is None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
            self.size += 1
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            node.prev = self.head
            self.tail = node
            self.size += 1
```

And you should modify a little also the `__str__` function

```
def __str__(self):
    vals = []
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        vals.append(node.val)
        node = node.next
    return ','.join((str(val) for val in vals))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The reason why you see this error is because you only let `add(self)` to have one positional argument, which is `self`. What you want is something like follows:

```py
def add(self, value):
    node = Node(value)
    if self.tail is None:
        self.head = node
        self.tail = node
        self.size += 1
    else:
        self.tail.next = node
        node.prev = self.head
        self.tail = node
        self.size += 1
```

Note that this answer doesn't look for your logic, only to fix your problem regarding positional arguments.

Also, `self` is a special keyword in Python used for instance variables and methods. When you create a new instance of Node as `node = Node()`, you automatically pass `self` argument, and the same goes for `add` method.

When you call `my_list.add(1)`, Python inherently understands it as

```py
my_list.add(self,1)
```

Of course, here `self` is equal to `my_list`. That's why Python tells you "I already got `self`, however, you've passed another value, so I will throw an error.